# Strange SIGPIPE in loop

Tags: c++, unix, signals, system-calls

After dealing with a very strange error in a C++ program I was writing, I decided to write the following test code, confirming my suspicion. In the original program, calling `send()` and `this_thread::sleep_for()` (with any amount of time) in a loop 16 times caused send to fail with a `SIGPIPE` signal. In this example however, it fails after 4 times.

I have a server running on port 25565 bound to localhost. The original program was designed to communicate with this server. I'm using the same one in this test code because it doesn't terminate connections early.

```
int main()
{
        struct sockaddr_in sa;
        memset(sa.sin_zero, 0, 8);
        sa.sin_family = AF_INET;
        inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &(sa.sin_addr));
        sa.sin_port = htons(25565);

        cout << "mark 1" << endl;

        int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &sa, sizeof(sa));

        cout << "mark 2" << endl;

        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        {
                cout << "mark 3" << endl;
                cout << "sent " << send(sock, &i, 1, 0) << " byte" << endl;
                cout << "errno == " << errno << endl;
                cout << "i == " << i << endl;
                this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(2));
        }

        return 0;
}
```

Running it in GDB is how I discovered it was emitting SIGPIPE. Here is the output of that: http://pastebin.com/gXg2Y6g1

In another test, I called `this_thread::sleep_for()` 16 times in a loop, THEN called `send()` once. This did NOT produce the same error. It ran without issue.

In yet another test, I commented out the thread sleeping line, and it ran all the way through just fine. I did this in both the original program and the above test code.

These results make me believe it's not a case of the server closing the connection, even though that's usually what SIGPIPE means (why did it run fine when there was no call to `this_thread::sleep_for()`?).

Any ideas as to what could be causing this? I've been messing around with it for a week and have gotten no further.

Answer (score 0):

Running this on my machine prints up to mark 3 once, as I expected it to. The fact that it does run several times on your end tells me that you have a server listening on port 25565, which you have not included in this question.

Your problem is that you are not testing to see whether the server, of which you have not told us, closed the connection. When it does, your process gets a `SIGPIPE`. Since you do not handle that signal, your process quits.

What you can do in order to fix this:

1. Start checking return values of functions. It wouldn't have helped in this particular case, but you ignore potential errors from both `connect` and `send`. I'm hoping this is because of minimizing the program, but it is worth mentioning.
2. Handle the signal. If you prefer to handle server closes from the main flow of your code, you can either register a handler that ignores the signal, or pass the flag `MSG_NOSIGNAL` to `send`. In both cases, send will return `-1` in such a case with `errno` set to `EPIPE`.
3. RTFM. Seriously. A simple `man send` and a search for `SIGPIPE` would give you this answer.

As for why the server closed, I cannot answer this without knowing what server it is and what protocol it is running. No, don't answer that question in the comments. It is irrelevant to this question. The simple truth of the matter is that a server you are talking to might close the connection at any time, and your code must be able to to deal with that.